# Is matinées du jour ouvrable the colloquial way to say workday mornings?

Tags: pluriel

I want to say “Workday mornings” as in “the mornings of the days I go to work” in French. I found both journée de travail and jour ouvrable as workdays. What the difference between the two and which is correct when saying workday mornings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Journée de travail*** is more used to define an amount of work, whatever the weekday, like *il faut encore une journée de travail pour terminer ce chantier* or *il se repose après sa journée de travail*  while *jour ouvrable* defines the days of the week during while regular work can legally be done.

The *[**jours ouvrables**](https://code.travail.gouv.fr/glossaire/jour-ouvrable)* span from Monday to Saturday (included) excluding holidays (*jours fériés*).

We also have the ***jours** [**ouvrés**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/ouvr%C3%A9)* that are like *jour ouvrables* but exclude Saturdays<sup>1</sup>. Here *ouvrables/ouvrés* are not related to *ouverts* (open) but to are cognates of *ouvrage*, *œuvre*, *opérer*. (from the Latin *opera*).

Assuming you don't work on Saturday mornings, you might use *ouvrés* with *matin*, but that's rare and not colloquial. [e.g.](http://www.vaucluse.gouv.fr/point-d-accueil-numerique-en-prefecture-et-sous-a11594.html):

> Sous-préfecture d’Apt
> accueil sans rendez-vous tous les **matins ouvrés** entre 8h30 et 11h30

If your talk about generic workdays, alternatives are :

> Les matins en semaine
> Les matins de la semaine
> Les matins de semaine

but in your case (the mornings of the days I go to work), better to say:

> Les matins où je travaille
> Les/mes matinées travaillées

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For most workplaces, Saturdays are excluded, but it is also possible for some of them to have *jours ouvrés* that include Saturdays but exclude Mondays.</sub>

Comment: I think *matinées travaillées* would be the less ambiguous, *en semaine* doesn't imply one goes to work (or just works). And one doesn't necessarily work on all *jours ouvrables* or *jours ouvrés*. [More here](https://www.lepavillondesentrepreneurs.fr/nombre-de-jours-ouvres-et-travailles-en-2021/).

Comment: @None Oui, j'ai ajouté ce sens, merci.